# FLAG_IMMUTABLE is causing wrong behaviour

Tags: android, geofencing, android-geofence, fusedlocationproviderapi

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

I'm sending broadcast using pending intent and I had to use the "or" condition to use both flags to prevent the crashes. But the problem is using FLAG_IMMUTABLE gives default values in "onReceive" in the broadcast, while using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT gives the correct values (apart from the crash).
Is there a way to handle this problem? or is there a way to use something else than pending intent

```
fun getPendingIntent(): PendingIntent{
    if (this::_pendingIntent.isInitialized)
        return _pendingIntent

    val intent = Intent(this,
        GeofenceBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

    val flags: Int
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    } else {
        flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    }

    _pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE,
        intent, flags)


    return _pendingIntent
}
```

BroadcastReceiver class:

```
class GeofenceBroadcastReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver() {

 override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

    val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)


      //here the value is null
      val geofenceList = geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences
      for (geofence in geofenceList) {
          Timber.d("GEOFENCE onReceive: " + geofence.requestId)
       }

    }
   }
```

Comment: FLAG_IMMUTABLE means final so you can not use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: @Style-7 so what's a good workaround?

Comment: May be use FLAG_MUTABLE